# OS X and Ubuntu on a USB-stick

Tags: dual-boot, usb, mac, macbook, macosx

what do you end op with if you follow [How to create a bootable USB stick on OS X](http://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)? will it delete OS X or can i use my Mac (OS X) normally when the usb-stick is not connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OS X even when the usb-stick is connected. **It will not delete OS X**
When you have the usb-stick connected you only need to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when your system starts the boot process and in the menu that will appear select the USB. You can return to OS X rebooting the computer.